# "Time jumped forward" in gmapping

Tags: slam, navigation, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using slam_gmapping like in link:[this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData), but with a live scanner and I'm getting messages like "Time jumped forward by [0.010211] for timer of period [0.010000], resetting timer (...)".

I am running it from a single computer (except rqt_logger_level) so I guess clock synchronisation shouldn't be the cause. But I updated both clocks with ntpdate to be sure (which didn't help).

I noticed that the problem seems to get worse if there is more load on the computer. Could the load be the cause? And in that case is there a way to increase the size of the allowed time jumps? (Or is there an other way to reduce the load for gmapping?)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/92581/%22time-jumped-forward%22-in-gmapping/) by [WLemkens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4068/wlemkens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2013-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi WLemkens,

you can follow 1 Answer from
http://answers.ros.org/question/94671/error-in-creating-2d-global-map-of-the-environment/#99961

let me know if it works.

---

Originally posted by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) with karma: 167 on 2013-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0